# Query function to select all columns of an imported data set, starting from a specific column

Tags: google-sheets, search, import, match, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to query specific columns of an imported dataset from a separate google sheet. Ideally, I would like to query all columns after the "product ID" column (refer to "Test Data Set"). The reason why I am doing this is that I need the product ID column to remain in a particular position in the "Final Destination Sheet" since the "Product ID"s will be used as a reference range for the index and match formulas on another tab of that sheet.

The formula I have so far to import and query the original dataset for the "Product ID" column is as so:

=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1aPpdSy5venMl97ayn7VwaOo_AcAtcoc6_l4a1loPhNI","Sheet1!A:D")}, "SELECT Col" &MATCH("Product ID", IMPORTRANGE("1aPpdSy5venMl97ayn7VwaOo_AcAtcoc6_l4a1loPhNI","Sheet1!A1:1"),0),1)

However, I am unsure how to make the formula understand to query up all the columns after the "Product ID" column. Do note, the test data set only has 4 columns and a set number of columns but the real data set I am working with will be dynamic so more columns can be added or deleted over time. (So I won't know what the finite column letter will be and if columns are deleted from the left of B then it might shift its position which is why I used the match function in my original formula to ID that specific column's location on the spreadsheet).

Thank you in advance!

Final Destination Sheet (where the data is imported to and where I am trying to query the original data for specific columns): [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c-wuUiVZY-w0vlbfs3lIdsKzl8rfxG-9dVTlhkFZxHg/edit#gid=1363171103)

Test Data Set (where the data is imported from): [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aPpdSy5venMl97ayn7VwaOo_AcAtcoc6_l4a1loPhNI/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the headers you can do:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("1aPpdSy5venMl97ayn7VwaOo_AcAtcoc6_l4a1loPhNI", 
 "Sheet1!A:D")), "where lower(Col1) matches 'product id|size'", 0))
```

---

### update:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1aPpdSy5venMl97ayn7VwaOo_AcAtcoc6_l4a1loPhNI", 
 "Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(1, MATCH("Product ID", 
 IMPORTRANGE("1aPpdSy5venMl97ayn7VwaOo_AcAtcoc6_l4a1loPhNI", 
 "Sheet1!1:1"), 0))&":1000")
```

assuming headers are in row 1 this will look for a column called product id and import it and all the columns to the right of it

Comment: In "where lower(Col1) matches 'product id|size'", does the symbol "|" equal to the use of ":" when we define a range in other functions like during import range? I tried "where lower(Col1) matches 'product id|color'" to see if I can query all the columns starting from "Product ID" but it didn't work. 

Also when we query in this format does it only query numerical data, I noticed it didn't query over text (ex. when I tried to query over color it only brought the header over and not the different colors).

Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanPoon no. | means OR logic so it will import only columns which have header named product id or size. in some cases there is a possibility that text or numerical data are left out. in such case use: `=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TO_TEXT(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("1aPpdSy5venMl97ayn7VwaOo_AcAtcoc6_l4a1loPhNI", 
 "Sheet1!A:D"))), "where lower(Col1) matches 'product id|size'", 0))` and no formula is able to copy over the colors only scripts can

Comment: Ah gotcha, that makes sense. Then I think the OR logic wouldn't really make sense for my use case since the real data set I am working with will be dynamic so more columns can be added or deleted over time. Plus since there are more than 40+ columns it wouldn't be efficient to update the formula with the column header names every time there is a change. Would there be any other solutions by any chance?

Comment: @JonathanPoon not sure if I understand your issue correctly... in your dataset, there is a column on unknown (or is it known?) position with header name "Product ID" and you want to get that column and all adjacent columns to the right of it. is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, I would like to locate "Product ID" column and grab all the columns to the right of it. The "Product ID" column is key because it is used as search keys reference in my index match functions so in the queried dataset I always need to have it as the leftmost column. Its position would be unknown since the original dataset would be dynamic so columns can be added or deleted over time (shifting the "Product ID" column's position.

Comment: @JonathanPoon answer updated

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for. Learned a lot about the application of "Transpose" and "Query" through this process, never crossed my mind to use import range in that manner but learning something new everyday!